# Filter and remove sentences that begin and end with a certain word in R

Tags: r, text, cpu-word, sentence

I am trying to filter words that begin with a certain word and end with it.
I have some text data, for example:

```
data <- c("No comment", "Nothing", "No clue", "No", "No", "I have no clue", "Noe")
```

Now I want to detect sentences that begin and end with a no. I tried

```
str_detect(data, "^No", negate = FALSE)
```

but obviously also Sentence 1, 3 and surprisingly also sentence 7 gets detected.

I don't know how to tell R to only detect the sentence if and only if it begins AND ends with the word "No".

Does anybody has an Idea?
I am new here so I hope my problem description was satisfying.

Looking forward to hear from you all!

Comment: None of the strings start *and* finish with a "No". Do you want to match strings that are exactly "No", i.e. a "No" with nothing afterward?

Comment: Yes that's the right description of the problem, thank you Claudio!

Comment: OK, I posted an answer with the code matching exactly "No" at the beginning of the line, with nothing afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data <- c("No comment", "Nothing", "No clue", "No", "No", "I have no clue", "Noe")
data <- c(data, "No and No", "No and YesNo")
grepl("^No(.*\\bNo)?$", data)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If the `"YesNo"` should indeed match, then remove the `\\b` from the regex.

Regex:

- `^No` - starts with the literal `No`;
- `(...)?$` - *optional* match at the end of the string; this means that both `"No"` and `"No something No"` will match;
- `.*\\bNo` - anything following by a word-boundary and the literal `No`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Can you explain to me how you got to this answer? How the single signs work and what they tell R? I would be really interested to understand this to the fullest. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit. Changed first element to start wih no and end with no:

```
new_data <- c("No comment no", "Nothing", "No clue", "No", "No", "I have no clue", "Noe")

library(stringr)
str_detect(new_data, "^No.*no$")
```

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lst <- unlist(data)
startsWith(lst, "No") & endsWith(lst, "No")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

lst[startsWith(lst, "No") & endsWith(lst, "No")] 
[1] "No" "No"
```

Comment: This is cool! I think it even works better than the other ideas. Do you know if I can also filter other words in the same function-line when I would like to detect different sentences (For example "Yes")? I tried
startsWith(lst, "No|Yes") & endsWith(lst, "No|Yes")
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can't make it work with `startsWith` and `endsWith`, but here is another solution: `grepl('^No|^Yes', data) & grepl('No$|Yes$', data)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a regexp that exactly matches "No", you can go with:

```
library(stringr)
data <- c("No comment", "Nothing", "No clue", "No", "No", "I have no clue", "Noe")
str_detect("^No$", data)

# > [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```